# SQL Server: Use a column to save order of the record

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm facing a database that keeps the ORDERING in columns of the table.

It's like:

```
Id  Name    Description Category    OrderByName OrderByDescription  OrderByCategory
1   Aaaa    bbbb        cccc        1           2                   3
2   BBbbb   Aaaaa       bbbb        2           1                   2
3   cccc    cccc        aaaaa       3           3                   1
```

So, when the user want's to order by name, the SQL goes with an `ORDER BY OrderByName`.
I think this doesn't make any sense, since that's why Index are for and i tried to find any explanation for that but haven't found. Is this faster than using indexes? Is there any scenario where this is really useful?

Comment: I believe you are confused as to what a table really represents. Tables are, by definition, unordered sets of rows. You are given no guarantee as to the order of rows unless you use an Order By. Indexes are an implementation specific feature to aid with searches. Indexes can be ordered ascending or descending, have multiple columns, where clauses and a host of other features. Thus, it makes no sense that an index would impact the sorting as the sorting is a declaration of the output you want and an index is a performance feature based on the filtering and sorting you requested.

Comment: This is more common when ordering a subset of data, e.g. each person in a directory may specify the preferred order for using contact information. Some may want Office Telephone first, others Mobile Telephone. An application would allow the users to Move Up/Move Down or otherwise adjust the entries in their list of contact information.

Comment: @Thomas i'm not the author of that "masterpiece". I'm just trying to figure out what the hell is that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can make sense for many reasons but mainly when you don't want to follow the "natural order" given by the `ORDER BY` clause.

This is a scenario where this can be useful :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce569/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Id] int, [Name] varchar(15), [OrderByName] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Id], [Name], [OrderByName])
VALUES
    (1, 'Del Torro', 2 ),
    (2, 'Delson', 1),
    (3, 'Delugi', 3)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce569/1/0)**:

```
| ID |      NAME | ORDERBYNAME |
|----|-----------|-------------|
|  1 | Del Torro |           2 |
|  2 |    Delson |           1 |
|  3 |    Delugi |           3 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY OrderByName
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce569/1/1)**:

```
| ID |      NAME | ORDERBYNAME |
|----|-----------|-------------|
|  2 |    Delson |           1 |
|  1 | Del Torro |           2 |
|  3 |    Delugi |           3 |
```

Comment: Nice, But supposing the Order is exactly what the SQL server order by column would give me, would it still make sense?

Comment: I don't think so...but may be it was created for a development purpose. May be this make SQL scripting easier...

Comment: ...but in fact, in can be very time consuming since you need to recalculate the sort value each time you change something related to one of those order columns like name, description or category.

Answer (score 2):

I think it makes little sense for two reasons:

1. Who is going to maintain this set of values in the table? You need to update them every time any row is added, updated, or deleted. You can do this with triggers, or horribly buggy and unreliable constraints using user-defined functions. But why? The information that seems to be in those columns *is already there*. It's redundant because you can get that order by ordering by the actual column.
2. You still have to use massive conditionals or dynamic SQL to tell the application how to order the results, since you can't say `ORDER BY @column_name`.

Now, I'm basing my assumptions on the fact that the ordering columns still reflect the alphabetical order in the relevant columns. It could be useful if there is some customization possible, e.g. if you wanted all Smiths listed first, and then all Morts, and then everyone else. But I don't see any evidence of this in the question or the data.

Comment: I use this for a rankings system for example. Where people have a certain rank which is updated periodically. Also it also make sense if you want to know the position of a record without calculating the entire set every time. In the case of the rankings, if a user wants to know his rank.

Comment: @Gilles Sorry, but the solution to that problem is very rarely to store the same redundant information twice. When you have a performance problem due solely to the cost of calculating the rank, you might want to consider indexes to support those queries before less ideal approaches like this.

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful if the ordering was customizable - that is, if users did not want to see the list in alphabetical order, but rather in some custom order.

An index on the int columns would be smaller than an index on the column that holds the actual text, but I don't see that there is any real benefit to this in most cases.